How to implement an extension method to check if a string contains the special characters such as !, @, etc... in C#
I am working on a school assignment and have to use extension method to find a string contains a special characters like '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*'.
namespace ExtensionMethodAssignment
{

        public class CheckID
        {
            public bool IsAllowedID(string id)
            {
                string specialChar = @"!@#$%^&*";
                foreach (var identification in specialChar)
                {
                    if(id.Contains(identification)) return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type your ID : ");
            string id = Console.ReadLine();
            
            if (id.IsAllowedID() == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID is not allowed. \n !, @, #, $, %, ^, &, and * are not allowed.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{id} is allowed.");
            }
        }

    }
}

I wrote the code above but I don't know how to use it as an extension method.
I guess it seems like just to make a simple empty method name IsAllowedID and then  add up on a Main method but I don't know how.

Have you read the programming guide for extension methods?

As a side note: you should try to write your code in a way to make sense (instead of writing code that just magically works). If you have a method name IsAllowedID and this method returns true, it should indicate that your ID is in fact allowed (not the opposite)

Thank all of you for responses. A lot of things to understand; I will read and see the guide, books and class note once again

There are 3 issues in your extension method implementation:

Extension methods should be in a non-generic static class.
Extension methods must be themselves static.
The string id parameter should be prefixed with this keyword.

You can see this in the Extension Methods documentation.
Fixed version:
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ExtensionMethodAssignment
{
    //-----vvvvvv--------------
    public static class CheckID  // The class is static
    {
        //-----vvvvvv------------------vvvv-----------
        public static bool IsAllowedID(this string id)  // The method is static and the parameter is prefixed with `this`
        {
            string specialChar = @"!@#$%^&*";
            foreach (var identification in specialChar)
            {
                if (id.Contains(identification)) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type your ID : ");
            string id = Console.ReadLine();

            if (id.IsAllowedID() == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID is not allowed. \n !, @, #, $, %, ^, &, and * are not allowed.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{id} is allowed.");
            }
        }
    }
}

Live demo
Note that you should include using System.Linq; in order to use the method for checking if a string contains a char (the String.Contains method without it supports a string only).
A side note:
IsAllowedID should either be named something like IsNotAllowedID, or reverse the return of true/false because at the moment it returns the opposite of wether the ID is valid.

Thank you so much for the help and even more for the live demo! and also for the guide link ! :)

I did the 'check mark' but yet cannot vote up due to lack of reputation. I'm sorry!

These are the rules here, no need to be sorry @Youngson.

Static extension classes in C# can be used like following :

public static class IdentityExtension
{
    private static Regex ValidationRegex = new Regex("[!@#$%^&*]");

    public static bool IsIdValid(this string id)
    {
        return !ValidationRegex.IsMatch(id);
    }
}


Since "IsIdValid" method takes a string with "this" keyword, this method is an extension and can be used like following :
var fooId = "!fooId";
Console.WriteLine(fooId.IsIdValid());

Output will be false in this scenario since "fooId" has '!' as an element.
